# Remove fade animation from toast message

Tags: android, toast

I am using a hack to display an overlay over a picture in Google TV using a constant toast message.

I would like to know if there is a way to further modify the toast to remove the fade in and fade out effect. Ideally I would like the overlay to appear instantly.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For this , i suggest we can **use a layout**(`FrameLayout`).
and by using a new layout above your current layout and adding view that looks similar to TOAST to the top layer

After that do one thing by making object of View as v
eg:-

```
View v;

   v.setVisiblity(GONE);
   v.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
```

This will make your view appear or hide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `FrameLayout` and create a new Layout layer above your current layout and add a view that looks like toast to the top layer.

Then you can use: `View.setVisiblity(GONE);` and `View.setVisibility(VISIBLE);`

to make your view appear and hide instantly.

[View.setVisibility Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29)

[FrameLayout example](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

I like a fade-in effect, but I was in need to cancel a toast message immediately without fade-out effect, since the toast message remained shown for a short moment even when the Activity was already exited.

I came to this solution to close (or actually hide) my toast message `t` immediately:

```
((TextView)t.getView().findViewById(android.R.id.message)).setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
t.setText("");
t.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
t.cancel();
```

I assume to set colors transparent is the only way to hide the fade effect with standard Toast layout.